# How profoundly did Bor Gullet affect Bodhi?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, character-development

In Rogue One: A Star Wars Story, Bodhi Rook is interrogated by the seemingly telepathic creature, Bor Gullet. Saw Gerrera gives us a small amount of background on Bor Gullet by saying:

> "Bor Gullet can feel your thoughts, No lie is safe. What have you
>   really brought me, cargo pilot? Bor Gullet will know the truth. The
>   unfortunate side effect, - is that one tends to lose one's mind."

He says this while Bodhi is in the process of being interrogated and there is nothing to make us believe that the full procedure (Whatever that is) was not completed.

Now Bodhi does seem a bit jumpy for the rest of the film. However, this is consistent with what little we see of Bodhi's character before his interrogation. He speaks quickly and often repeats sentences for emphasis.

This is not to say, however, that Bodhi appears completely sane for the rest of the film. However, he does not seem to have 'lost his mind' as it were.

So are we meant to believe that Bodhi got lucky and remained sane after Bor Gullet's interrogation? And if so, is there an explaination for this? Or are we meant to believe that he was in fact turned insane? And if so, why does he seems so crazy beforehand?

Comment: This is pretty will cover in a similar question over on movies https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65783/why-wasnt-the-imperial-pilot-in-rogue-one-made-insane-or-affected - basically, he was affected... And "losing" one's mind does not prevent you from finding it again